# Decision tree model running for long time

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, decision-tree

I am running my decision tree model using rpart package in R. Here is what I am doing,

1. Loading my data using read.csv
2. Remove unwanted columns
3. Split my dataset in to training and test
4. Fitting my model on the training set
   -- This is running for whole day.

Here is the summary of my dataset.

```
'data.frame':   117919 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Database          : Factor w/ 2 levels "DBIL","DBPD": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Market_Description: Factor w/ 1 level "MY (PM)": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Manufacturer      : Factor w/ 21 levels "21 Century","Abbott Lab",..: 4 3 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Brand             : Factor w/ 133 levels "","21 Century",..: 34 26 34 34 34 34 26 26 26 26 ...
 $ Sub_Brand         : Factor w/ 194 levels "","0-6 Bulan",..: 9 6 9 9 9 9 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ Age_Group         : Factor w/ 5 levels "","Adultenr",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ FMT_Category      : Factor w/ 10 levels "Adult Powders (excl Super Bev)",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
```

Here is my script for model..

```
fit <- rpart(FMT_Category~Database+Market_Description+Manufacturer+Brand+Sub_Brand+Age_Group, data=trainingset)
```

It has only 117919 observations. I checked the memory.limit in my R and it says 8065 , also mem_used says 40 MB. I am not getting any error, but the model keeps running for a day. so I am not sure what to check here. I expected R to give at least some crappy tree, so I can start from there. I thought it has something to do with the factors, so I read the data with stringAsFactors=FALSE. Still it runs forever. I tried the same data in my python script and weka and it runs fast without any error. Please let me know what I am missing or point me in a right direction on what I should be checking.

**Edit** -- I just noticed that the issue is the number of levels in Brand and Sub_Brand , this is making the model run forever as it has to run recursively. Any suggestion to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Brand and Sub_Brand as integers.
2. Get rid of Market_Description which has only 1 level, and no help for decision tree model.

Comment: Yeah I have removed Market_Description. Converted Brand and Sub_Brand as integers, but thats giving me branches like brand > 1, which is of not much useful i think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [H2O package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h2o/h2o.pdf) for decision trees, random forests and neural networks. 
See `h2o.gbm`, `h2o.randomForest`. This package lets you use all your computer resources.

You can fin and example:

```
library(h2o)
conn <- h2o.init()
demo(h2o.randomForest)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about your dataset but it would be useful if you look your factor variables and try to decrease your factor levels. Is 194 level in Sub_Brand really necessary? How many of data are assigned to those certain levels?

Also, since PCA is not a good approach on categorical data on most cases, you can try one-hot coding as recommended in https://www.quora.com/Can-one-use-dimension-reduction-algorithms-like-PCA-for-categorical-variables-Any-suggestions-on-what-techniques-can-be-used/answer/Gaurav-Dangi-1?srid=YgDw.